# How to center logo background img and text in header?

Tags: html, css

I'm stumped by something that feels like it should be simple!

I'm trying to center a logo in the centre of a `<header>`. The logo is made up of an `<a>` with a background image which is the logo icon and the anchor text is the logo name. I have the logo icon centred using `margin: 0 auto;` on the `<h1>` but can't find a good solution to centering the icon and the text together as one unit.

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo Name</a>
   </h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
header h1 {
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a.logo {
  font-size: 33px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a jsFiddle with an example of your code. It will help us help you.

Comment: You should set the width: 100px; .. and then set margin: 0 auto;

Comment: CSS added. Looks like part of the problem was with my width!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
<style>
    .logo{
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding-left: 120px; /* the space between the start of your logo and your text */
        padding-top: 30px; /* the vertical space between the top and your text, to center the logo*/
        display: block; /* very important since normally anchors are inline */
        background: url(path/to/logo.png) top left no-repeat; /* obviously :) */
    }
</style>
```

It really don't need to be inside an h1.

When you see results, yo may not see it centered, well, measure your unit, and specify a width and a height inside the .logo rules above.

Comment: Ok thanks will give this a go. I put the anchor inside an h1 as I want  the anchor text to be picked up by screen readers as the main heading for the site. Am I on the wrong track with that!?

Comment: It's not that wrong, but it will be better if you put the h1 inside the anchor. I usually put the logo as an img element, too. i.e. `<a class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png" alt="logo name" /><h1>logo name</h1></a>`. It's more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

you can position the background using css.

```
background-position:center;
```

you can also define it by pixels or percent

```
background-position:20px 50px;
background-position:50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have put background url left it should be center

try this

```
background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat center;
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work.

```
<header style="align:center">
```

Comment: Should be `text-align`, and inline styles should be avoided.